# How to switch on and off file writer appending?

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

I am appending text to CSV file in a loop. Problem is, the whole process takes too long time +- 1 hour (because of server requests, but that doesn't matter). I want to be able, in case of program failure in the middle of the process, to rewrite the file when I run it again.

That means, normally I want to append to CSV but if it is first loop (the loop where headers are added, also does not matter), I want to have my appending turned off.

Here is the code which checks if it is loop with headers (the very first one) or other:

```
FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);
        if (!headers.equals("")) {
            // here is the point which will not happen twice, just if i re-run the program
            writer.append(headers);
            writer.append('\n');
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            // write values to the file
            writer.append(values.toString());
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried adding this `writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);` to `else` and this: `writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);` to `if`, didn't help.

If it doesn't look clear for you, let me know please.

Comment: Why don't you check if file is present before creating writer? Assuming that file will only be created for the first time it writes

Comment: You could also just delete the file and recreate it at the beginning of your write method.

Comment: I might use that, but how can I delete the file if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your program knows whether or not to append inside the conditional, you could create your writer inside the conditional, too:

```
if (headers.length != 0) {
    writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);      // Do not append
    // here is the point which will not happen twice, just if i re-run the program
    writer.append(headers);
    writer.append('\n');
} else {
    writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true); // Append
    // write values to the file
    writer.append(values.toString());
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Please check my edit, I already tried that and in the end of the program, file had just few records, probably the last loop.

Comment: @OndrejTokar What this means is that sometimes a non-empty `headers` variable is passed to your method at the point where you don't expect it, very close to the end of the output.

Comment: Do you wanna know what was the problem? That I did writer.flush in the if. That means I was almost right, but you were right. Thanks